what problem of my Rust code causes BorrowMutError?
I write a function to remove list node in Rust:
pub struct ListNode<T: Copy> {
    val: T,
    pub next: Option<Rc<RefCell<ListNode<T>>>>,
}

pub fn remove<T: Copy>(node: &Rc<RefCell<ListNode<T>>>) {
    if node.borrow_mut().next.is_none() {
        return;
    }

    if let Some(next) = node.borrow_mut().next.take() {
        let new_next = next.borrow_mut().next.take();
        node.borrow_mut().next = new_next;
    }
}

When I run the test code, the error is below:
thread 'tests::test_remove' panicked at list.rs:xx:xx:
already borrowed: BorrowMutError.

I change the code as below and the test is passed:
pub fn remove<T: Copy>(node: &Rc<RefCell<ListNode<T>>>) {
    if node.borrow_mut().next.is_none() {
        return;
    }

    let curr_next = node.borrow_mut().next.take();
    if let Some(next) = curr_next {
        let new_next = next.borrow_mut().next.take();
        node.borrow_mut().next = new_next;
    }
}

What wrong with the first part of the code?

The issue is that you call node.borrow_mut() once and then node.borrow_mut() again, which creates the second mutable borrow and it panics

Singly-linked-lists can (and should) be written with Box, no need for Rc and RefCell.

Also, mandatory reference: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/.


if let Some(next) = node.borrow_mut().next.take() {
    let new_next = next.borrow_mut().next.take();
    node.borrow_mut().next = new_next;
}


if let and match have a particular property which is inconvenient here: any temporary values in the scrutinee expression (the thing after the =, here node.borrow_mut().next.take()) have their scope extended to the entire if let or match. This is done so that it is possible to operate on an expression that borrows temporaries. For example, suppose you wanted to hang onto a mutable reference to the next field instead:
if let Some(next) = &mut node.borrow_mut().next {
    // now `next` is an `&mut Option<Rc<RefCell<ListNode<T>>>>`

This mutable reference is borrowing from the std::cell::RefMut that was returned by borrow_mut(), so the RefMut has to be kept alive that long.
In your case, that's inconvenient, but the ideal solution is to avoid calling borrow_mut() twice anyway:
pub fn remove<T: Copy>(node: &Rc<RefCell<ListNode<T>>>) {
    let mut node_mut = node.borrow_mut();
    if let Some(removed) = node_mut.next.take() {
        let new_next = removed.borrow_mut().next.take();
        node_mut.next = new_next;
    }
}

Notice that in this version, there are only two borrow_mut() calls — one for each of the two nodes that need to be mutated. Also, you don't need to check is_none(), because take() will return None in exactly that case.

Complete test program:
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ListNode<T: Copy> {
    val: T,
    pub next: Option<Rc<RefCell<ListNode<T>>>>,
}

pub fn remove<T: Copy>(node: &Rc<RefCell<ListNode<T>>>) {
    let mut node_mut = node.borrow_mut();
    if let Some(removed) = node_mut.next.take() {
        let new_next = removed.borrow_mut().next.take();
        node_mut.next = new_next;
    }
}

pub fn new<T: Copy>(vals: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> Option<Rc<RefCell<ListNode<T>>>> {
    let mut last = None;
    for val in vals {
        last = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(ListNode {
            val,
            next: last.take(),
        })))
    }
    last
}

fn main() {
    let list = new([1, 2, 3]);
    dbg!(&list);
    if let Some(node) = list.as_ref() {
        remove(node);
    }
    dbg!(&list);
}

